# RxJs array of http calls

Tags: angular, rxjs

I make an http request which returns Observable with array of products. For each of this product I need to make http call in order to get the details.
How to make it in parallel using RxJs. Now I have a products.forEach and eventually get this working but this uses external (to my method) BehaviorSubject.
I'd prefer return kind of concatenated object with all the details.

```
    return this.apiService.getCart().pipe(
      map(({ id, products, quantity }) => {
        products.forEach(({ productId }) => this.getProduct(productId).subscribe((product) => this.cart.products.push(product)));
        return { id, quantity }
      })
    )}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use the `forkJoin` operator and then return the product-details array as part of an object:

```
return this.apiService.getCart().pipe(
    switchMap(({ id, products, quantity }) => {
        const obs = products.map(({ productId }) => this.getProduct(productId));
        return forkJoin(obs).pipe(
            map((products) => ({ id, quantity, products })),
        );
    }),
);
```

Comment: Fantastic - it solved all my problems :) Thanks a lot man :)

Answer (score 1):

`from()` can take many items, one of which is an array. It will emit each item as one, from there you can execute an http request for each of the items. Once concatMap finishes, you can convert the result back to an array.

```
this.apiService.getCart().pipe(
  concatMap(({products}) => from(products).pipe(
    mergeMap(({productId}) => this.getProduct(productId))
  )),
  toArray(),
  tap(products => this.cart.products = products),
)
```

Comment: Will try this, not entirely sure how exhaustMap works especially together with concatMap (which resolves call one after another as I get it). Anyway - thanks for this - it will definitely help me to master the topic. :)

Comment: I think you need to use `mergeMap` instead of `exhaustMap` or else you will end up with an array that contains only a single element; the first product.